# Screen/Database query keep on loading/executing unless sql service is restarted

Tags: sql-server, database, model-view-controller

I am using MVC razor in one of the Web Application using .Net

One of the screen in my web application has 2 DropDownList, 1 button and 1 Grid. When I click on 1st DDL, the screen instead of focusing on 2nd DDL it starts to keep on loading.. and gives exception: `the timeout period expired prior to completion of the operation`

DDL select query is: `select * from Table where year='2014'and name='pqr'`(used in code behind Entity Framework) which throws this exception. Same thing is happening in DB, when I run the above LINQ query in SSMS, it keeps on executing.

If I restart SQL Service, everything starts to work normal and the result is shown but after some time if I try same then again the same issue occurs. In this case, I need to restart the sql service again and again which shouldn't happen.

In SSMS, I checked Activity Monitoring and found that sometimes some SPId's are getting blocked and that time only screen/query keep on loading/executing.

Using `DBCC INPUTBUFFER(spid);`I came to know which Stored Procedure / Table is blocking (please correct if my understanding is wrong here). I also tried using `with (NOLOCK)` on certain tables inside Stored Proc, which also didn't workout for me.

How can I resolve this issue at DB level? My application is already live.

**Note**: This issue occurs intermittently.

Comment: Check the query of the spid at the head of the blocking chain. Perhaps the problem is a long-running transaction that needs query/index tuning.

Comment: @DanGuzman: I checked the spid query by using DBCC INPUTBUFFER(spid), and found Stored Proc and tables related to it. But the DDL query is really simple then why is that issue happening ?

Comment: To find out what your query is waiting for use sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks, if it's bloked it also will be shown along with bloking spid, but it can be someone else

Comment: @user3196511, was it the query executed by the `Blocked By` spid that you checked?

Comment: @DanGuzman: using DBCC INPUTBUFFER(spid) shown me Stored Proc and Tables related to blocked by spid. The query I mentioned in my posted question is the one used in selecting the DDL (that query is used in code behind LINQ)

Comment: @sepupic: I will try that forsure.Thanks